# How to configure uri address for Spring Integration Web Service inbound-gateway?

Tags: web-services, spring-integration

Do you know how to configure the uri for Spring Integration Web Service inbound-gateway ?  Currently, I have to use the defaultEndpoint.

Here is my configuration:

```
<ws:inbound-gateway id="inbound-gateway" request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel" marshaller="hrMarshaller" unmarshaller="hrMarshaller"></ws:inbound-gateway>

 <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="inbound-gateway"/>
</bean>
```

I have read the Spring Integration, inbound gateway, but didn't understand.

What I need to do when I have 2 inbound-gateway?

Thank you and best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh that is very simple !

For @Bean

```
@Bean
public UriEndpointMapping uriEndpointMapping() {
    UriEndpointMapping uriEndpointMapping = new UriEndpointMapping();
    uriEndpointMapping.setUsePath(true);
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("/ws/abc", "cas-inbound-gateway");
    uriEndpointMapping.setEndpointMap(map);
    return uriEndpointMapping;
}
```

For XML

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="usePath"  value="true"/>
    <property name="endpointMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="/ws/abc" value="cas-inbound-gateway"></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

@-@